# Symmetric difference of sum of sets included in sum of their symmetric differences

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I've got the following problem. I am supposed to prove that:
$$(A1\cup A2)\oplus(B1\cup B2)\subseteq (A1\oplus B1) \cup (A2\oplus B2)$$
where $\oplus$ is the symmetric difference.
I know that from definition:
$$X\oplus Y = (X\setminus Y)\cup (Y\setminus X)$$ what can also be written as: $$X\oplus Y = (X\cap Y')\cup (X'\cap Y)$$
I tried messing with the left side and get to the right side and vice versa using various set transformations, but I had no luck. I've also tried other approach, using:
$$(A1\cup A2)\to x\in A1 \lor x\in A2...$$
but still I got stuck and got nothing similar to the other side.

This is kinda upsetting especially that I got graphical solution quickly (refer to link). I would be grateful for any help, clues or tips on how to approach this problem.

There is also a second question asking if:
$$(A1\cap A2)\oplus(B1\cap B2)\subseteq (A1\oplus B1) \cup (A2\oplus B2)$$
is true for any $A1, A2, B1, B2$. For what i tried to do, again, graphically, I came to conclusion it is indeed true.

[My tries to do things graphically - imgur](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TiaL8.jpg)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take any $x\in (A_1\cup A_2)\oplus (B_1\cup B_2)=\left((A_1\cup A_2)\setminus(B_1\cup B_2)\right)\bigcup\left((B_1\cup B_2)\setminus (A_1\cup A_2)\right)$. Then either $x\in (A_1\cup A_2)\setminus(B_1\cup B_2)$ or $x\in(B_1\cup B_2)\setminus (A_1\cup A_2)$.

**Case $1$:** $x\in (A_1\cup A_2)\setminus(B_1\cup B_2)$

Then $x\in A_1\cup A_2$ and $x\not\in B_1\cup B_2$. It follows that $x\in A_1\setminus (B_1\cup B_2)$ or $x\in A_2\setminus(B_1\cup B_2)$. Since $A_1\setminus(B_1\cup B_2)\subseteq A_1\setminus B_1$, we have that if $x\in A_1\setminus (B_1\cup B_2)$, then $x\in A_1\setminus B_1$. Similarly, $A_2\setminus (B_1\cup B_2) \subseteq A_2\setminus B_2$, so if $x\in A_2\setminus(B_1\cup B_2)$, then $x\in A_2\setminus B_2$. Therefore, $x\in (A_1\setminus B_1)\cup (A_2\setminus B_2)$.

**Case $2$:** $x\in(B_1\cup B_2)\setminus (A_1\cup A_2)$.

By an almost identical argument, you can show $x\in(B_1\setminus A_1)\cup(B_2\setminus A_2)$.

Therefore, $x\in(A_1\setminus B_1)\cup (A_2\setminus B_2)\cup (B_1\setminus A_1)\cup(B_2\setminus A_2)$.

But $(A_1\setminus B_1)\cup (A_2\setminus B_2)\cup (B_1\setminus A_1)\cup(B_2\setminus A_2)=(A_1\oplus B_1)\cup (A_2\oplus B_2)$.

Comment: Thank you for your contribution. This solution is great, I think I would never get to this myself.
So now, talking about the second task, I probably can assume that because: union of A1 and A2 is included in sum of A1 and A2 (same for B), the second statement will also be true regardless of A1, A2, B1 and B2?

Comment: I don't think this works. The second one is true (but your venn diagram isn't quite right - see http://math.gmu.edu/~eobrien/Venn4.html for what a venn diagram with 4 sets should look like). To prove it, use a similar approach to the above: if $x\in(A_1\cap A_2)\setminus (B_1\cap B_2)$, then either $x\not\in B_1$ or $x\not\in B_2$, so $x\in (A_1\cap A_2)\setminus B_1\subseteq A_1\setminus B_1$ or $x\in (A_1\cap A_2)\setminus B_2\subseteq A_2\setminus B_2$. And then do the same thing for $x\in (B_1\cap B_2)\setminus (A_1\cap A_2)$.

Comment: The reason I don't think your suggestion works is that $E\subseteq X, F\subseteq Y$ does not imply $E\oplus F\subseteq X\oplus Y$